# How to reference a Sass stylesheet within SVG in a React App

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, sass

For background, I am trying to load SVG icons in my react app and am using the object tag so that I can manipulate the color of the icons easily.

In this [guide](https://svgontheweb.com/), they say:

> If you want to use external styles, which are mostly much easier to work with and maintain, you can’t use  or background-image. If you are using  you need to reference your stylesheet internally from the SVG file (see code following). Remember: if you do this the SVG will also not be able to know what its parent class is (i.e. the ) so don’t try to use that in its styling. Inline SVGs don’t need this added and therefore can be slightly easier to work with in this sense.

and provide this code example:

```
// Add to very start of SVG file before <svg>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
```

```
// In style.css
.firstb { fill: yellow; }
.secondb { fill: red; }
```

To give you an idea of how my files are organized, my `src` folder contains an `assets` folder along with my `components` folder. My `style.scss` file lives within the `src` folder as well.

I'm having trouble figuring out what to add to the top of my svg files. My understanding of sass is that it would usually compile `style.scss` to `style.css`, however, when I look at my sources in dev tools it shows that `style.scss` is being loaded directly. Is this just because I'm still in development mode?

Anyways, I've tried the following (none of which have worked):

`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="./style.scss"?>`
`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>`
`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.scss"?>`

It would be a huge help if anyone knows how I can get this to work! Let me know if there's any other information I can provide. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to assume that you'd need to compile `style.scss` to `style.css`, so first ensure that only the CSS is being referenced in the SVG. This is the most straightforward way to get this to work, but a better solution would be to import your styles once in your root HTML template instead.

Now, if you're using React it's likely that you're also using a bundler such as `webpack`. You can tell bundlers like webpack to handle non-JS imports such as Sass files by using loaders. There is a [`sass-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader) for webpack that will allow you to import Sass files, however you may also need to add the [`svg-inline-loader`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/svg-inline-loader/) so that you can import the SVG directly.

I think with both loaders, what will happen is that webpack will start bundling your React app, see that an SVG is imported, grab it and see that it is referencing a Sass file, grab the sass file and compile it, and then output the `styles` in your `index.html` file. Please let me know if this solution works for you!

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, you could just add the styles inline in the SVG via a regular old `style` tag. That'd be much easier than wrangling webpack + loaders.

Comment: Interesting idea with the inline `style` tag, but the issue is that I need to be able to toggle the color of the SVG. I have a lot of icons on buttons that have an unclicked, hovered, and active state. I wonder if that's something I can accomplish inline though, since the SVG wouldn't know anything about the state of the button?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Not exactly what I was hoping for, but it works for me.

There's a react-svg package that handles an ajax request and pulls the svg in as a normal svg tag. This allows me to edit with my sass file.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg